# Jupyter Notebook: Plot

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I converted my price column as seen below into ints so I could plot the price. However, when I plot, I receive the plot as shown below. Am I missing something, or what exactly is this showing? Thank you.

*Jupyter notebook plot*
[image: Jupyter notebook plot]

Answer (score 0):

In your attached image, the y-axis is displaying the long integers in scientific notation.

To control the representation used in the display of the y-axis, one solution is to use Matplotlib's `set_major_formatter()` method since Pandas plot is based on Matplotlib underneath, and combine that with Python's modern string `.format()` method , see [here](https://mkaz.blog/code/python-string-format-cookbook/) and [here](https://pyformat.info/). (Note that while neither of those last two resources seem to cover money representation, they have good coverage and are useful for understanding the general method conventions.)

SOLUTION:
Based on [here](https://keithwithdata.medium.com/this-week-i-learnt-how-to-add-to-ticks-on-matplotlib-graphs-f67ccee1f3dc) for formatting for money using Matplotlib's `set_major_formatter()` method and [here](https://pythonguides.com/python-format-number-with-commas/#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20to%20format%20a,thousand%20places%20starting%20from%20left.&text=After%20writing%20the%20above%20code,appear%20as%20a%20%E2%80%9C%205%2C000%2C000%E2%80%9D.) for adding commas in the string formatting:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'make' : ["Ford","Chevy","Nissan","Toyota","BMW"],
    'Price':[40000,50000,700000,55000,2200000]
    })
ax = df["Price"].plot()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter('${x:1,.2f}')
```

To get what I meant about adding the commas via the string formatting, compare the plot produced from:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'make' : ["Ford","Chevy","Nissan","Toyota","BMW"],
    'Price':[40000,50000,700000,55000,2200000]
    })
ax = df["Price"].plot()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter('${x:1.2f}')
```

Note what you see for `'${x:1,.2f}'` vs. `'${x:1.2f}'`.

The variations above were used just to more fully illustrate the abilities of the '`.format()`' method. **Specifically, you may prefer for the '`yaxis.set_major_formatter()`' line the following** since you didn't seem to want decimal places displayed for your cost values:

```py
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter('${x:,.0f}')
```